# It is okay to mount 2 encrypted disks with same UUID

Tags: lvm, luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

I have 2 harddrives. 1 was empty - let's call it hard2 and other had a working Linux OS - lets call it hard1. I use `dd` to copy hard1 to hard2, but I could not boot with hard2. I had a error: `inode seems to contain garbage`. So I used `fsck` and now when I boot I get errors because there are missing files in /sbin and some other directories. I mount hard2 and saw that directories are empty.
I want to boot hard1 and mount the hard2. Then copy them with cp -avr hard1 to hard2
They have same UUID. I just want to ask is there any problem if I will mount it like that ? Because I will have 2 harddrive with same UUID. Can I get some bug or error that will destroy or crash my hard1 ?

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs are supposed to be *universally unique*, not just on your system but anywhere.

Duplicate UUIDs will lead to confusion, wrong devices being mounted, without you noticing; you should definitely change them. Usually that's fairly easy to do, most things that use UUIDs also provide some way to change them. Search the relevant manpages.

Change UUID for LUKS:

```
cryptsetup luksUUID --uuid=$(uuidgen) /dev/thing
```

Change UUID for encrypted ext4 filesystem:

```
tune2fs -U random /dev/mapper/encryptedthing
```

Regarding your other problems, it's quite unclear what happened there, maybe you used `dd` wrong or you ran it while the filesystem was mounted and being written to, leading to a corrupt copy. In that case you should consider doing it over altogether.

Comment: It's a ext4 filesystem. I need to run both commands cryptsetup luksUUID --uuid=$(uuidgen) /dev/thing and after that use luksOpen and then  tune2fs -U random /dev/mapper/encryptedthing ?  I think system will stop working if I will change UUID and I will need to change in system configurations old UUID with new. Can I generate a new UUID, copy files that I need and then return back the old UUID ?
I copied using clonezilla dd mode.

Comment: (I doubt you can fix this with `cp`, but ...) if you don't change UUID you have to double check which device got mounted where using `lsblk`, `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts`, etc. And before you reboot, change the UUIDs of the device you *don't* want to be mounted.